# CSS background is not working properly in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image, android-browser

I have 8 html div's. I have set background of all divs with different image, All are displaying properly except 2 div's in IE8 and in default android browser. If i set any other image for these two div's background, they will also work. But if rename those two images and set them, they wont work. I am confused. Below is the code

```
     #tabs-8{
        background: url(../images/banner/290/open-house.jpg);
      }
      #tabs-6 {
        background: url(../images/banner/290/our-trainers.jpg);
      }
```

Is there any issue with those images Or Is this the issue in IE8.

Comment: Can you give link on your site with this problem?

Comment: http://115.115.80.139/

Comment: a don't see any poblem on IE8...

Comment: Could please share the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem :) Your images doesn't load on IE8. If you enter this link `http://115.115.80.139/images/banner/290/our-trainers.jpg` on address bar in IE8 you don't see image. I think that problem on server or image. Try resave image with another name or upload it on other hosting

Answer (score 2):

Using shorthand property for background might cause the problem. So just use `background-image: url('path');` if you don't specify any other values.

If you use shorthand property, use like this at least:

```
background: url('path') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to call the image using `background-image: url` Property.

`<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">Example of a DIV element with a background image:</div>`